# Magento 1.5 CE - need help with shipping rules excluding certain categories from free international shipping

Tags: magento-1, shopping-cart-price-rules, shopping-cart, free-shipping

I need help with the shipping rules. Basically - free shipping on everything over $100 *excluding* any item from category 907, 110 for free international shipping. I need to charge the buyer with shipping if they order a product from the above category. Even if its just a single item from the category.

[image: I took a screenshot to show but I'm not sure how to set the actions.]

Answer (score 2):

Turn it around and use `product subselection` instead of `product attribute combination`

[image]